# Clojure printing #object instead of value?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to learn Clojure and I'm starting with some basics such as functions, concatenation, lexicon replacement, etc. The one I'm stuck on currently is replacement. I've created a function called `test` that accepts two parameters `v` and `v2`; it's purpose is to replace periods with whitespace using `clojure.string/replace`:

```
(defn replace-lexicon [value lexicon replacementValue]
(println str(clojure.string/replace value lexicon replacementValue)))
  
(replace-lexicon "this.is.a.test" "." " ")
```

The expected output is:

> this is a test

However, the output has additional information with it:

> #object[clojure.core$str 0x35aea049 clojure.core$str@35aea049] this is a test

I tried searching for answers on how to remove it, but I'm not finding anything conclusive. Drawing on my experience with other languages, I can't help but feel this is demonstrating that what's being printed isn't a string but rather an object. Unfortunately though, this is just an educated guess, and, I haven't been able to prove it.

---

What is `#object...`, and how do I remove it to correct my output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close!  The extra `str` is the problem.  Here is a version written with unit tests from [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
  ))

(defn replace-lexicon
  [value lexicon replacementValue]
  (str/replace value lexicon replacementValue))

(dotest
  (is= "this is a test" (replace-lexicon "this.is.a.test" "." " "))
  (is= "this is a test" (replace-lexicon "this#is#a#test" "#" " "))
  )
```

A hint is in the substring `clojure.core$str` in the error msg, which is the compiler's way of representing the function `clojure.core/str`.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Functions in clojure are called like `(f x y)`, not `f(x y)`. In your question you mistakenly call `str` in the second way, and your comment here suggests you are making the same mistake applying Alan Thompson's correct answer, by calling `replace` incorrectly.

Comment: @amalloy that combined with Alan's answer solved it! Thank you both!